# Angular pass deferred error from service to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular app I have a controller. The controller has a method which calls an asynchronous function in a service called `Service`.  This is the controller code:

```
$scope.controllerMethod = function(){       
        Service.serviceMethod($scope.x, $scope.y).then(function(data){
                //request succeeded, so do nothing
        }, function(data){
                //there was an error, show error message
        });
}
```

And this is the `serviceMethod` within the `Service` service:

```
serviceMethod: function(x, y){
        return $http.post('save', {
                id: x, type: b
        }).then(function(data){
                //update variables in the service
        }, function(data){
                //send error message to controller
        });
}
```

When the `Service` method calls the server, the server will return an error if necessary.  How can I send that error response to my controller? With the current setup, no matter if the `$http` request returns success or error, the deferred in the controller always executes it's success method. I want to invoke the error method for the deferred in the controller passing it the data from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write the Service as:

```
serviceMethod: function(x, y){
        return $http.post('save', {
                id: x, type: b
        }).success(function(data){
                // do things Service related when call is successful
        }).error(function(data, status){
                // do things error related...
        })

}
```

And then reference it in a controller like this:

```
Service.serviceMethod($scope.x, $scope.y).success(function(data){
        // request succeeded, so do nothing
}).error(function(data, status){
        // error occured, do whatever
});
```

This works like a charm... Here is [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: Worked great thank you! I have no idea why though. I thought `.then()` was just another way to write `success` and `failure` callbacks. Any idea why I would be seeing different behavior? It even says in the docs you linked: "Since the returned value of calling the $http function is a promise, you can also use the then method to register callbacks, and these callbacks will receive a single argument – an object representing the response."

Comment: I really have no idea, but my wild guess would be that returning a function to the service method as I described above somehow exposes the 'success' and 'error' methods to the controller. Not sure...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. As far as I can tell in both cases we are returning the deferred from the service method. They both return `$http(...)`