# Need to convert controller in to factory?

Tags: angularjs

My goal is to be able to exchange data from two controllers, Ive been told I can create a service and then inject the data in to other controllers - I however am having trouble converting this ('somethingDetailCtrl') controller in to a service/factory..

```
somethingApp.controller('somethingDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
    function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
        $http.get('/assets/javascripts/something/something/' + $routeParams._id +'.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.thething = data;
    });
}]);
```

would anyone be kind enough to walk me through this (just the converting somethingDetailCtrl in to a factory), i have about 2 days worth of angular knowledge so any explanation is welcome.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not very clear to me. Could you share/explain more information about the data you want to share between your controllers?

Comment: Ah ok the factory in my question is the factory I made to pull a list, it's the only factory I've written. The controller above it also needs its insides converted in to a factory - I'm having trouble with that one "somethingsetailctrl" - I need help building a factory for this controller. Sorry for the unclear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An angularjs factory constructs a new service using a function that returns an object with all the data and behavior the service exposes.  The factory is a singleton.  Your example controller is looking to expose an http GET and could be written like this if we didn't care about error checking:

```
angular.module('something',[]).factory('Something', function($http) {
    return {
        getSomething: function(callback) {
            $http.get('/something').success(function(data, status) {
                callback(data, status);
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The factory function's arguments are its dependencies.  In the example above we only used $http. We can use promises by adding $q ... again we are skipping error checking in this example:

```
angular.module('something',[]).factory('Something', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        getSomething: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('/something').success(function(data, status) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}
```

You can consume either of the above from your controller.  To use the first factory example, you could do the following where the second argument to the controller function is the service generated by the factory:

```
angular.module('somethingApp').controller('somethingDetailCtrl', function ($scope, Something) {
    Something.getSomething(function(data) {
        $scope.thething = data;
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, this factory is well-written. Now you just have to inject it into your controllers. For example, to extend the controller above, you would change it to be like:

```
somethingApp.controller('somethingDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'somethingListFactory',
    function($scope, $routeParams, somethingListFactory) {
        somethingListFactory.list().then(function(data){
             $scope.thething = data;
        });
    });
}]);
```

**EDIT:** I stand corrected, remove the below part from your factory (it is futile):

```
.then(
     function(result) {
          return result.data;
     });
```

Comment: I think both factory and controller should have `$promise` functions. BTW, offtopic, i'm also Bosnian (Bihać) and would like to connect, maybe we can collaborate on some projects.

Comment: Okay, if you would like to have callbacks in both functions, see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26242446/angular-pass-deferred-error-from-service-to-controller/26242566#26242566
p.s. How do I contact you? :)

Comment: Email me: deno.kajda `-@-` gm-com